# C++ wxWidgets GetSizeFromText() returns bigger size on high dpi

Tags: wxwidgets

I have been using `wxWidgets 3.1.6` to create a `C++` `Windows 11` application, which I haven't been having a good experience with so far.

My application has been using absolute positioning for a long time, so I decided to switch to using `wxSizers` instead.

With the help of `wxSizers`, my `widgets` are sized and laid out for me automatically.

---

I managed to use `wxSizers` with my application without having to `hardcode` any sizes.

However when checking to see what my program looks like on `high dpi`, I see that my `wxTextCtrl` isn't sized properly.

This is because even though I didn't hardcode any widgets, I did do something similar with my `wxTextCtrl`.

---

**Consider this code:**

```
/* I am trying to set a wxTextCtrl's size based on the number of characters in it
/* In this case the number of characters is 162.
/* */

wxFont bigfont;           // Creating font
bigfont.SetPointSize(11);

auto textctrl = new wxTextCtrl(panel, wxID_ANY, "");   // Creating textctrls
text->SetFont(bigfont);

std::string number_of_characters = std::string(162, ' ');            
wxSize size = textctrl->GetSizeFromText(number_of_characters);    // When checking the variable "size" in the debugger, it shows a different value for high and low dpi
textctrl->SetMinSize(size);
```

I am trying to set the `wxTextCtrl's` size by making it display a given amount of characters, in this case, it's **162**.

When checking the variable `size` in the debugger :

---

**On low dpi:**

`x = 499 , y = -1`

**On high dpi:**

`x = 644 , y = -1`

**Note:** I don't care about the **y** axis since it will be calculated automatically by the sizers.

---

How Do I use `wxControl::GetSizeFromText()` in such a way that I can make my `wxTextCtrl` have the same size for `high` and `low dpi` ??

If I can't do that `( I have realistic expectations )` then I need some other way to size the `wxTextCtrl`.

Without sizing it myself, The widget would be sized differently which would be bad for UX reasons.

I've tried using `FromDIP()` and `ToDIP()` and dividing the size with `wxWindow::GetDPIScaleFactor()`.

---

### They didn't work though:

`FromDIP()` returned a bigger size, when I needed to decrease the size:

`x = 830 y = -1`

`ToDIP()` returned a smaller size :

`x = 531 y = -1`

Dividing my size with `wxWindow::GetDPIScaleFactor()` returns the same size as `ToDIP()`.

---

I checked the value of `wxWindow::GetDPIScaleFactor()` :

- It returned **1** for low dpi
- It returned **1.25** for high dpi

---

Here is what the problem looks like :

[image]

As you can see the `wxTextCtrl` on `high dpi` is much longer then the `wxTextCtrl` on `low dpi`.

This is what is looks like without `FromDIP()` and `ToDIP()`.

---

**Thank you.**

**Edit :**

Here is my reproducible example , please test this on `high` and `low dpi` to see the difference:

[Sample Project](https://www.filemail.com/d/ehzfsatkfrikfro)

This is only valid `7 days` from now...

**Edit 2 :**

**Here is the source code:**

wxFrame.cpp

```
#include "wxFrame.h"

MyFrame::MyFrame() : wxFrame(nullptr,
    wxID_ANY,
    "Sample",
    wxDefaultPosition,
    wxDefaultSize,
    wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
{


    wxFont bigfont;
    bigfont.SetPointSize(11);

    wxFont smallfont;
    smallfont.SetPointSize(10);


    wxPanel* panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);

    wxBoxSizer* outerSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    wxFlexGridSizer* fgs = new wxFlexGridSizer(3, 0, 3);
    // row 1
    int hello = 4;
    auto text = new wxStaticText(panel, wxID_ANY, "Input File:");
    auto textctrl = new wxTextCtrl(panel, wxID_ANY, "");
    auto button = new wxButton(panel, wxID_ANY, "   ...   ", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT);
    text->SetFont(bigfont);

    // Getting textctrl size from text size
    std::string spaces = std::string(162, ' ');
    double dpi = wxWindow::GetDPIScaleFactor();
    wxSize size__ = ToDIP(textctrl->GetSizeFromTextSize(
        textctrl->GetTextExtent(spaces)));
    //  size__ /= dpi;
    textctrl->SetMinSize(size__);

    fgs->Add(text, 0, wxALIGN_RIGHT | wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wxALL, 4);
    fgs->Add(textctrl, 0, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 4);
    fgs->Add(button, 0, wxALL, 4);

    // row 2

    auto text_ = new wxStaticText(panel, wxID_ANY, "Output Folder:");
    auto textctrl_ = new wxTextCtrl(panel, wxID_ANY, "");
    auto button_ = new wxButton(panel, wxID_ANY, "   ...   ", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT);
    text_->SetFont(bigfont);


    fgs->Add(text_, 0, wxALIGN_RIGHT | wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wxALL, 4);
    fgs->Add(textctrl_, 0, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 4);
    fgs->Add(button_, 0, wxALL, 4);

    fgs->AddGrowableCol(1);

    outerSizer->Add(fgs, 0, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 16);   // <- border at all sides

    panel->SetSizer(outerSizer);
    outerSizer->SetSizeHints(this);
}

MyFrame::~MyFrame()
{
}
```

wxFrame.h

```
#include "wxIncludes.h"



///// Our Main Frame
/**/

class MyFrame : public wxFrame {

public :

    // Sample Button
    wxButton* sample = nullptr;

    // Constructor
    MyFrame();


    // Destructor
    ~MyFrame();


};
```

wxApp.h

```
///// wxWidgets includes header
/**/

#include "wxIncludes.h"
#include "wxFrame.h"


class myApp : public wxApp {
public :
    
    ///// Startup function
    /**/
    myApp();
    ~myApp();

    virtual bool OnInit();
};
```

wxApp.cpp

```
#include "wxApp.h"

///// Initalize the app
/**/

IMPLEMENT_APP(myApp);


// Constructor
myApp::myApp()
{}

// Destructor
myApp::~myApp()
{}


///// Startup function
/**/

bool myApp::OnInit()
{
    // Creating our frame
    MyFrame* myFrame = new MyFrame();
    myFrame->Show();

    // Continue to show window
    return true;

}
```

wxIncludes.h

```
///// Winsock header
/**/

#include <winsock2.h>


///// Winsock header
/**/

#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/zipstrm.h>
#include <wx/dir.h>
#include <wx/wfstream.h>
#include <wx/progdlg.h>
#include <wx/dirdlg.h>
#include <wx/statline.h>
```

Comment: what is the DPI value of your monitor for HighDPI? Can you make a smallest possible patch to `minimal` sample showing that? I also presume you include the manifest with DPIAware v2 value?

Comment: Hi Igor, No I don't include any manifest file , I use Visual Studio to enable high dpi. My monitor DPI scaling is 125% scaling. My monitor DPI is 120 x 120. Of course you would ask me to try the samples. I will make a test program , NOT a patch to the samples. I've told you so many times that I use vcpkg

Comment: @Igor I have updated the question to have a sample project

Comment: can you copy/paste the source code here? Also, yo and I both know vcpg package is buggy. Why yo are still using it? It is very straightforward to build the library with MSVC...

Comment: I know , my team decided to use vcpkg some time ago.... as it is easy to do so. They don't want to build it manualy. :|

Comment: @Igor I've updated the question to include the source for my test project

Comment: but you can. What stops you?

Comment: @Igor 

it's my team. Also in vadim's answer, he said that I need to use hardcoded paths
     for the wxTextCtrl , if I want it to have the same size in all resolutions , so I am going   
     to go with his answer.

Comment: as Vadim also said, it is not recommended.

Comment: Yeh , I actually decided to live with the bigger textcontrols its only about 10 pixels wider.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that `GetSizeFromText()` doesn't return the same size in high DPI is not a problem at all -- actually it would be a problem if it did return the same size, as then the control would be twice smaller when using 200% scaling, for example.

What you seem to be complaining about it is that its result doesn't scale perfectly with the DPI scaling factor, i.e., if I understand you correctly, you'd expect it to return `1.25*500 == 625` instead of 644 you actually get when using 125% scaling. This is not totally unexpected neither because:

1. Fonts metrics don't scale exactly with DPI scale.
2. Text control size is computed using DPI-dependent font and mostly DPI-independent margins.

The difference of 19 pixels is a bit more than I'd expect, but, again, you can't count on it being exactly the same anyhow.

If you really must have the same size in any DPI (why?), you need to scale the desired size in **D**PI-**I**ndependent **P**ixels (called DIPs in wx API) using `FromDIP()`, e.g. you could use `FromDIP(wxSize(500, -1))` instead. It is *not* recommended to this, `GetSizeFromText()` should be more precise, but if you want to have exactly the same size in all resolutions, you could do it like this.

Comment: I guess I have to hardcore the size then.

Comment: Hi @VZ.  , If font metrics don't scale exactly with the DPI , then how do I fix the font ????